# Sull'uso, o—meglio—sul non uso, di 'benone' quale valutazione dei compiti scolastici

Tags: history

Quando ero alla scuola primaria, quella prima nota come elementare, gli insegnanti usavano valutare i compiti con termini quali, fra l'altro, 'bene'  e 'benissimo'. E c'era anche 'benino', sì.

Allora mi chiedo, se c'erano 'bene', 'benissimo' e 'benino', perché non c'era anche 'benone'?

Answer (score 6):

[Benone](http://www.dizionario.org/d/?pageurl=benone-17039):

Avverbio  (informale) accrescitivo  di *bene*. 
Usato principalmente riferendosi allo stato di salute:

> - Come stanno i tuoi? Benone!!

Usato speso con intento ironico:

> - Come va l'economia in Italia? Benone direi!!.

Date le caratteristiche e l'uso comune, il termine non si presta ad essere usato come giudizio di un lavoro scolastico.